# Using Dynamics CRM 2011 UR11 Outlook client to connect to a UR14 server

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, outlook-addin

I've got several users using the Outlook client to connect to my CRM 2011 server.  Currently they are on the UR11 client version.

Can I update the server to UR14, without an interruption of service for them?

I.E. will the Outlook client UR11 connect to a UR14 server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you can connect, but expect a few problems like disconnections and diverse errors.
http://dynamics.co.il